# Rebuilding labeling from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, arcgis-online, arcade

I have multiple layers in an ArcGIS Pro project with vbs scripted labeling. I have created a Web Map on ArcGIS Online that uses these feature classes. I wish to rebuild the labeling in ArcGIS Online but ArcGIS Online does not support vbs label scripting, only arcade. The labels are various fields stacked upon one another on separate lines in a box.
They look like this:

```
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

Each field is above/beneath the other one.

How do I rebuild these labels?

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-create-multiline-labels-with-concatenated-text-u-000026373#:~:text=Type%20%2B%20TextFormatting.,to%20add%20a%20line%20break.